# Highlight coordinates on Canvas Oval boundaries

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am drawing oval using bezierCurveTo method of canvas. I have to highlight the points on boundary of oval(same as oval shape in powerpoint). I want the exact position of all eight coordinates to place them on canvas. Please refer to attached screenshot[image]

Comment: this might help : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unit_circle_angles_color.svg

Comment: that seems to be too complicated..Is there any easy way to find this? can we use any other function to draw oval on canvas using mouse events?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to use a Bezier to create an oval/ellipse - it's mathematical inaccurate and will just cause headache when you want to use points such as in this case.

I would suggest to create your own ellipse function - it's easy; this creates an ellipse as a path which you can fill and stroke etc.:

```
function drawEllipse(cxt, cx, cy, rx, ry) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(cx + rx, cy);
    for(var a = 0, step = 0.02, max = Math.PI * 2; a < max; a += step)
        ctx.lineTo(cx + rx * Math.cos(a), cy+ ry * Math.sin(a));
}
```

Now, to get those edge points all you need to do is have a similar function (or modify the previous) doing the same but with less granular steps as well as returning the calculated points - count is number of points you want. The resulting array here in this example will return points arranges as `[x1, y1, x2, y2, ...]` - this is something you can adjust as you need:

```
function getEllipsePoints(cxt, cx, cy, rx, ry, count) {

    var points = [],
        a = 0, max = Math.PI * 2,
        step = max / count

    for(; a < max; a += step)
        points.push(cx + rx * Math.cos(a), cy+ ry * Math.sin(a));

    return points;
}
```

Now you can plot the points at the edges as you want (and have a mathematical correct ellipse as well as hit points for mouse).

**[Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/7X7yJ/)**

Result:

[image: Result from demo]